# Entity Framework query returning different results during debug

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm facing a weird issue I'd call the schrodinger bug. I have a entity framework query I do using Linq that at runtime returns something, but when I debug it returns something else.

I'm searching for an item in a list of entities of a table by Id. I added a breakpoint at the row after the query is executed and at the first run it returns an object which id supposed to match with the id "-1". But I don't have any Id set to "-1" id in that table. If I bring the execution pointer back to the query and I execute it again, then it returns the expected value: null.
I'm adding here a couple of screenshot of the debugger to make it clearer.

First pass:

[image]

Second pass:

[image]

As you can see in the first screenshot, the Id to search for is set to "-1" but the object returned has an id set to "18".

Here's a more complete snipped of the code causing the bug.

```
foreach (var answer in question.Answers)
{
    if (answer.Sentence != null)
    {
        var a = q.Answers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == answer.Id);

        if (a == null || answer.Id == -1)
        {
            if (q.Answers == null)
                q.Answers = new List<Answer>();

            a = new Answer();
            q.Answers.Add(a);
        }

        a.IsRight = answer.IsRight;

        var id = answer.Sentence.Id;
        var qryResult = dataContext.Sentences.Where(s => s.Id == id);
        a.Sentence = qryResult.Any() ? qryResult.First() : null;

        if (a.Sentence == null)
        {
            a.Sentence = new Sentence()
                        {
                            Text = answer.Sentence.Text,
                            IsQuestion = false
                        };
        }
    }
}
```

As requested, here are the entity models:

```
public class Exam
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }
}

public class Question
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Sentence Sentence { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
    public virtual Answer GivenAnswer { get; set; }
}

public class Answer
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Sentence Sentence { get; set; }
    public bool IsRight { get; set; }
}

public class Sentence
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public bool IsQuestion { get; set; }
    public string RelatedTopics { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Just at first glance, you can optimise 2 lines of code to `a.Sentence = dataContext.Sentences.Find(id)`

Comment: Can you show your entity models please? Do you use lazy loading for Sentence, i.e. `public virutal Sentence Sentence {get; set;}`?

Comment: @Georg I just added the models and yes, it's using lazy loading. Before the code on the snipped I have a query to the EF using Inlcude like this:
`var examToUpdate = dataContext.Exams.Include(x => x.Questions).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == exam.Id);`


@Chris I know, thanks. The code is like that because I broke it down trying to debug the issue (without any result so far :P)

Comment: in plain English, just well me what you have key wise and what you are wanting to get. your query looks weird... to messy. i.e. your looking over question answers for what? BTW the -1 is probably coming from the view... i.e. they didn't select and option from UI... hence why you are at where your at. If you dont know where -1 is coming from then the problem is there first.

Comment: Also please include all code, i.e. what is q